# one way conditional statement in binary variable linearization

Tags: optimization, constraints, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to write a one-way conditional statemen with binary variables. my condition is

```
(if x=1 then y=0)
```

and it is the **only** condition that should be met. So I want to have:

```
(if x=0 then y=0 or 1)
(if x=1 then y=0)
(if y=0 then x=0 or 1)
(if y=1 then x=0 or 1)
```

the problem of using `y<=1-x` is that the statement is two-way(for x and y: (if x=1 then y=0) and (if y=1 then x=0) and I want to have **only** (if x=1 then y=0)).
I have already tried out large M and some of other methods which I knew, however I did not achieve any results. 
Can anyone please help me. I stuck on this problem for a couple of days...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If we have x=1⇒y=0 then it follows that y=1⇒x=0. You cannot have one without the other. This is sometimes called Modus Tollens in propositional logic.

Comment: Thanks. You mean it is not possible even if I use additional variables(like binary z)?

Comment: If x=1⇒y=0 then it follows that y=1⇒x=0. No matter what.